# DIY Cleaning Solution for Quartz

Tags: cleaning, kitchen-counters, quartz

I have a water/castile soap/lemon essential oil mix I use for cleaning. We've recently moved and have quartz countertops at our new place. I'm having trouble finding information on what is/isn't safe for quartz countertops. Is the above mixture safe for them if wiped off with a damp cloth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz is a man-made product of natural stone components in a resin binder.   It is almost as heat resistant as granite (but the resin can be damaged) but is significant more stain resistant than granite.  It is not porous and does not have to be sealed as natural stones do.

That said, you should wipe up spills quickly with regular detergent and take reasonable care.  You're going to have to find out the actual manufacturer of your countertops to get an specific care recommendation, but there is no lack of generic sources on the internet.

https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-clean-quartz-countertops/

Answer (score 0):

Castile soap/lemon essential oil no doubt is effective and (may be) appropriate for human skin, but it has no place in cleaning a counter. Use very dilute dish washing detergent in warm water optionally followed by a clean wet rag.